# How to set unique string primary key in flask-sqlalchemy for API endpoint

Tags: python, api, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am building a Rest API using Flask dan Flask-SQLAlchemy. Just wonder, are there any ways to generate a unique ID string primary key? this key will be used for identity API endpoint, like:

POST v0.2/users/4q2VolejRejNmGQB/messages

Instead of

POST v0.2/users/123/messages

I am playing with http://hashids.org/, but seems like had a problem because the primary key will be generated automatically after I save the data while hashids need to generate given integer

Comment: How about set a field with unique constraint?

Comment: use uuid library

Comment: got it, I am using uuid and base64 to generate friendly unique url. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the solution. I am using uuid for generating unique primary key and base64 to make it friendly.

```
import re
import uuid
import base64

def uuid_url64():
    rv = base64.b64encode(uuid.uuid4().bytes).decode('utf-8')
    return re.sub(r'[\=\+\/]', lambda m: {'+': '-', '/': '_', '=': ''}[m.group(0)], rv)
```

here is example of the implementation

```
user1 = UserModel(user_id=str(uuid_url64()), name='rizkiaditya')
```

Comment: But are you still seting the primary_key proprery to True in the UserModel declaration?

Comment: yes, since primary_key should be unique, UUID can handle that.

Comment: If you use `sqlalchemy_utils` dedicated type `UUIDType`, you can declare the primary key like this: `uuid = Column(UUIDType, primary_key=True)`

Comment: `sqlalchemy_utils` works, but if you are using `Flask-Migrate`, it doesn't generate the migration version properly. I had to change manually the parameters passed to the `UUIDType`.